# How to overflow elements on horizontal manner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well ,, how to make these blue squares overflow horizontally so that horizontal scrollbar appear (for the page not the div) and make it flexibale so that if new squares are added it can expand .. and Anyone can use CSS , Javascript or Jquery no problem at all ! AND THANKS IN ADVANCE

```html
    <head>
    <style>
    .test {
    background: blue;
    width: 372.1478174125px;
    height: 230px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    
    }
    .horizontal {
    background: gray;
    height: 640px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class= "horizontal">
    <div class = "test"> hello </div><div class = "test"> hello </div>
    <div class = "test"> hello </div>
    <div class = "test"> hello </div>
    <div class = "test"> hello </div>
    <div class = "test"> hello </div>
    <div class = "test"> hello </div>
        <div class = "test"> hello </div>
        <div class = "test"> hello </div>
        <div class = "test"> hello </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `float: left;` on the item, because `white-space: nowrap;` on the container do not have any effects on floating item themselves.

And don't forget to add `overflow-x: auto;` to the container.

```css
.horizontal {
  background: gray;
  height: 640px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto; /* new */
}

.test {
  background: blue;
  width: 372.1478174125px;
  height: 230px;
  margin: 5px;
  /* float: left; */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal">
  <div class="test"> hello </div>
  <div class="test"> hello </div>
  <div class="test"> hello </div>
  <div class="test"> hello </div>
  <div class="test"> hello </div>
  <div class="test"> hello </div>
  <div class="test"> hello </div>
  <div class="test"> hello </div>
  <div class="test"> hello </div>
  <div class="test"> hello </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks alot it worked but one last thing how can I make these squares over flow by 2 lines ( not one line as in this code ) using javascript or jquer or css all accepted :D

Comment: I think adding a <br> before the <div> wherever you want to wrap could be the easiest way - [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eyqjqR). You may want to post a new question for that.